# partial update in sksamuel/elastics4

Tags: elastic4s

Is there a way to tell Elastic to ignore not existing document when doing partial update on some document id:

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s._

 val request = update(id).in(indexAndType).doc(someDoc) 

 elasticApi.execute(request)  // returns a Failure with DocumentMissingException if a document with the given id doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (of course) catch the exception, or do a get request first to see if the document exists, and only then do the update, but the request you want doesn't exist at time of writing.

```
  val f = client.execute {
    get("index", "type", "id")
  }.collect {
    case Right(resp) if resp.result.found => client.execute {
      updateById("index", "type", "id").doc(someDoc)
    }
  }
```

The above code is from release 6.1.1.

Comment: Right, but there are two problems with this solution: first, in concurrent environment there could be another update in between this thread's read and update which can cause VersionConflictEngineException, and second, performance wise it will basically cost extra read (because update is always read->update). I am looking for an Elastic function "update or ignore if the document doesn't exist" and a corresponding sksamuel.elastic4s method.

Comment: It doesn't exist. That's why I've given you the second best option. I'd personally just catch the exception, as that will involve a single read rather than two.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure it doesn't exist.